# Overlaying Image Matrices Python

Tags: python, numpy

I have two images of pixel art. I want to take some features from one image and replace the pixels in the original image. I've written an example code. What I want it to do is to only take the items in "L" that are not "tr" and overwrite the values in "M" with them. I am using numpy where to accomplish this. Unfortunately it always seems to simply output "L" as the whole new array N. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

The code at the end outputs this as an image based on the rgb colours defined as the variables.

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# library to interact with the operating system
import os

# gets path to be used in image creation mechanism, using os
dirname = os.path.dirname(__file__)

# sets final image dimensions as 480x480 pixels
# the original 48x48 pixel image will be expanded to these dimensions
dimensions = 480, 480

x=1

bg = (255,186,241)
bb = (214,168,102)
tr = (0,0,0)
tl = (222,191,140)

M = [
    [bg,bg,bg,bg,bg,bg],
    [bg,bb,bb,bb,bg,bg],
    [bg,bb,bb,bb,bg,bg],
    [bg,bg,bg,bg,bg,bg],
    [bg,bg,bg,bg,bg,bg],
    [bg,bg,bg,bg,bg,bg]
    ]

L = [
    [tr,tr,tr,tr,tr,tr],
    [tr,tr,tr,tr,tr,tr],
    [tr,tr,tr,tr,tr,tr],
    [tr,tr,tr,tl,tr,tr],
    [tr,tr,tr,tl,tr,tr],
    [tr,tr,tr,tr,tr,tr]
    ]

N = np.where(L == tr,M,L)


# convert the pixels into an array using numpy
array = np.array(N, dtype=np.uint8)

# use PIL to create an image from the new array of pixels
new_image = Image.fromarray(array)
new_image = new_image.resize(dimensions, resample=0)
imgname = dirname + '/testfolder/' + (str(x)) + '.png'
new_image.save(imgname)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make your arrays numpy arrays so that `np.where` works correctly:

```
M = np.array([
    [bg,bg,bg,bg,bg,bg],
    [bg,bb,bb,bb,bg,bg],
    [bg,bb,bb,bb,bg,bg],
    [bg,bg,bg,bg,bg,bg],
    [bg,bg,bg,bg,bg,bg],
    [bg,bg,bg,bg,bg,bg]
    ])

L = np.array([
    [tr,tr,tr,tr,tr,tr],
    [tr,tr,tr,tr,tr,tr],
    [tr,tr,tr,tr,tr,tr],
    [tr,tr,tr,tl,tr,tr],
    [tr,tr,tr,tl,tr,tr],
    [tr,tr,tr,tr,tr,tr]
    ])
```